# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List to 'Models.CustomerViewModel'

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, repository, viewmodel, ilist, icollection

I am trying to pass a list of data containing two objects that are contained in a custom interface,

My interface consists of

```
public interface ICustomersAndSitesRepository
{
    IQueryable<CustomerSite> CustomerSites { get; }
    IQueryable<Customer> Customers { get; }
    IQueryable<ICustomersAndSitesRepository> CustomerAndSites { get; }
}
```

Then my repository i have this method

```
public IQueryable <ICustomersAndSitesRepository> CustomerAndSites
    {
        get { return CustomerAndSites; }
    }
```

Then i have my viewmodel

```
public class CustomerSitesListViewModel
{
    public IList<CustomerSite> CustomerSites { get; set; }
    public PagingInfo PagingInfo { get; set; }
    public CustomerViewModel Customers { get; set; }

}
```

And my controller action

```
public ViewResult List([DefaultValue(1)] int page)
{

    var customersWithSitesToShow = customersAndSitesRepository.CustomerAndSites;
    var viewModel = new CustomerSitesListViewModel
    {                
        Customers = customersWithSitesToShow.Skip((page - 1) * PageSize).Take(PageSize).ToList(),
        PagingInfo = new PagingInfo
        {
            CurrentPage = page,
            ItemsPerPage = PageSize,
            TotalItems = customersWithSitesToShow.Count()
        }
    };

    return View(viewModel);  //Passed to view as ViewData.Model (or simply model)
}
```

This line throws an error as im trying to pass the collection to my paging function thats expecting a list.

```
    Customers = customersWithSitesToShow.Skip((page - 1) * PageSize).Take(PageSize).ToList(),
```

The error is

```
 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List to 'Models.CustomerViewModel'
```

Is there a way to convert the list that is being returned so that it can be used in the viewmodel?

This is the customer view model

```
public class CustomerViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public string PrimaryContactName { get; set; }
    public string PrimaryContactNo { get; set; }
    public string PrimaryEmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string SecondaryContactName { get; set; }
    public string SecondaryContactNo { get; set; }
    public string SecondaryEmailAddress { get; set; }
    public DateTime RegisteredDate { get; set; }
    public string WasteCarrierRef { get; set; }
    public string UnitNo { get; set; }
    public string StreetName { get; set; }
    public string Town { get; set; }
    public string County { get; set; }
    public string Postcode { get; set; }
    public byte[] ImageData { get; set; }
    public string ImageMimeType { get; set; }
    public SiteViewModel Site { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Which line is throwing the error? If it's "return View(viewModel);" then can you provide the <page> tag from the view that is being called?

Comment: @bzarah, thanks ive updated the question to show the line thats causing the error, its where i am trying to pass the collection to the paging function.

Comment: Is the variable "Customers" declared as type 'Models.CustomerViewModel'? Must be, right? That would be the issue

Comment: @Liam You should show us your `CustomerViewModel` class. By name only, I'd guess you're trying to set an instance of `CustomerViewModel` to a list--which obviously aren't equivalent types

Comment: @bzarah, yes its defined in the viewmodel as                     public CustomerViewModel Customers { get; set; }

Comment: @David, thanks, ive updated the question to show the customer view model.

Comment: OK, the error message is pretty straightforward. GenericList can't be assigned to CustomerViewModel. You are trying to jam a list into a single object.

Comment: Using the viewmodel is the right approach to wrap up multiple sets of data. You just need to look at code carefully to figure out the issue here. I'm not familiar with your domain, but as an outsider, I think your model is a little confusing, so I'm having trouble getting a nice answer for you.

Comment: Part of my confusion is the fact that you have two lists. One for customers, one for sites. It would be easier to work with if one of those lists was merged into the other: List of customers that each had a list of sites, or the reverse. Again, I'm not familiar with your app, but the controller code should be nice and clear. If it's confusing here, it's going to be a real mess in the View :)

Comment: @bzarah, having the two lists was the only way i can get access to both objects in the display template, i.e.                          <%= Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Customers.CustomerName) %>
<%= Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Customers.Site.AddressLine1) %>

Comment: @bzarah, in my customer view model i am including the customer site which allows me to access both objects in the view. This isnt a requirement, just the only way i can access both objects in the view. How can i merge the lists into one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says: the property `CustomerSitesListViewModel.Customers` is of type `CustomerViewModel`, but you are trying to assign a `List<CustomerSite>`.

Did you mean this instead:

```
CustomerSites = customersWithSitesToShow
                  .Skip((page - 1) * PageSize)
                  .Take(PageSize)
                  .ToList()
```

or maybe this:

```
Customers = new CustomerViewModel(customersWithSitesToShow...),
```

Comment: hi i am using the viewmodel in an attempt to access properties for both objects, both customer and customer sites, i have updated the question to show my customer view model. I have been unable to find another way to access 2 onjects from one view/display template.

Comment: thanks again, when using your second suggestion it throws an error stating that customerview model doesnt contain a constructor that takes 1 argument.

Comment: Please ignore the second suggestion (I made it before you posted your CustomerViewModel, it was only a guess)